# Something is wrong with my MatLab 2nd Order ODE solver, and I can't figure out what it is.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I'm trying to do one of [MIT's Computational Methods in Aerospace Engineering](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-90-computational-methods-in-aerospace-engineering-spring-2014/projects/MIT16_90S14_proj1.pdf) projects. I've written the code for Project #1 part 1, and I'm getting a very reasonable solution using the euler, midpoint, heun, and classic RK methods. However, when I run an error analysis on these data sets compared to a really small dt classic RK run, the orders of the errors don't match up. Starting with midpoint, i'm getting a max error of around 0.055 for my euler, midpoint, and huen methods. This is telling me that my midpoint and heun methods are somehow not increasing in order from the euler method, and I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. Here's the code for my midpoint method:

```
t_val=zeros(1,n); %initial values
h_val=zeros(1,n); 
H_val=zeros(1,n);
A_val=zeros(1,n);
a_val=zeros(1,n);

a_val(1)=a0; %0<a<0.08 radians


for i=2:n
    t_val(i)=t_val(i-1)+dt;

    %{
    ka_2=(dt/2)*A_val(i-1);
    kh_2=(dt/2)*H_val(i-1);
    kA_1=dt*A1(a_val(i-1),A_val(i-1),h_val(i-1),H_val(i-1));
    kH_1=dt*H1(A_val(i-1),a_val(i-1),h_val(i-1),H_val(i-1));
    kA_2=dt*A1(a_val(i-1)+ka_2,A_val(i-1)+(kA_1/2),h_val(i-1)+kh_2,H_val(i-1)+(kH_1/2));
    kH_2=dt*H1(A_val(i-1)+(kA_1/2),a_val(i-1)+ka_2,h_val(i-1)+kh_2,H_val(i-1)+(kH_1/2));

    H_val(i)=H_val(i-1)+kH_2;
    A_val(i)=A_val(i-1)+kA_2;
    a_val(i)=a_val(i-1)+2*ka_2;
    h_val(i)=h_val(i-1)+2*kh_2;
    %}
```

t_val is the time array

h_val is the plunge data point array (trying to solve for h(t))

a_val is the pitch data point array (trying to solve for a(t))

H_val is the first derivative of h(t) data point array

A_val is the first derivative of a(t) data point array

A1(a,A,h,H) and H1(A,a,h,H) are the second derivatives of a(t) and h(t) respectively. They are functions of four variables, and they are found by solving the original system outlined in the project definition for the second derivatives.

The "k" notation is based on an example of the midpoint method I found in a textbook. These "k" variables are just temporary stepping stones, building the real solution at the end.

In one of the solutions for the project, the writer provides a discretization for the midpoint method as follows:

[image]

I tried to re-write my code based on this, but it confused me, because it uses three instances of the iteration, n. It uses n-1, n, and n+1. How can I write a code that can use all three of these indexes? What is wrong with my code in the first place? General information always welcome.

Comment: The method in the image is also called "central Euler method" or Nystroem method. It is weakly stable and will reflect the error of the first step in the global error. Your implemented method seems to be inconsistent in the fraction of the substep in the stages. Were you trying to implement the "stone-age" interpretation of the implicit midpoint method?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. My implementation is not necessarily based on the one in the picture. I did try to write one based on the one in the picture, but I didn't get very far because I didn't know how to solve the problem I put at the end. Does there seem to be something wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method seems to be tailored for a system $\dot x=X$, $\dot X=F(x,X)$. Let's shorten that to $\dot y=f(y)$. The method you apply is the explicit midpoint method
\begin{align}
k_1&=f(y)\,dt, \\
k_2&=f(y+\tfrac12k_1)\, dt, \\
\hline
y_{+1}&=y+k_2 .
\end{align}
Detailed to the components $x$ and $X$ this gives
\begin{align}
 k_{1x}&=X\,dt,& k_{1X}&=F(x,X)\,dt,\\
 k_{2x}&=(X+\tfrac12k_{1X})\,dt,& k_{2X}&=F(x+\tfrac12k_{1x},X+\tfrac12k_{1X})\,dt,\\
\hline
  x_{+1}&=x+(X+\tfrac12k_{1X})\,dt,&X_{+1}&=X+k_{2X}.
\end{align}
This reconstruction of the method exhibits that your computation of the final updates of $a$ and $h$ is incomplete, using only an order 1 correct increment which renders the whole method as implemented only order 1, even if the theoretical method is order 2.

Comment: You have made my day! Thank you for such a concise and understandable answer to my question. The problem was indeed how I was calculating ka1 and kh1.